# Need to know best tool for making software prototypes

Tags: prototype

Any one can tell me please which tools are provided by IBM for making prototype of softwares.

Thanks,

Deepak

Comment: Over the years I've found that the single best tool to prototype software is a good old, low-tech pencil and notepad.

Comment: Do you want the best tool, or a list of the tools IBM makes?

Comment: I disagree that a model is the same thing as a prototype.  To me, a prototype is a slimmed down realization of an idea that can actually run on a computer.  No UML model is going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Rational products mainly provide modeling tools.
And **rational statemate** provides prototyping tool
See: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/statemate/